# Kernel of $M\to M[U^{-1}]$ and primary decomposition of $(0)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

I am working on exercise 3.12 from Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra* and I am having trouble parsing the question.

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over the Noetherian 
ring $R$. Given any multiplicatively closed set $U \subset R$, show that the intersection of the primary components of $0$ in $M$ corresponding to those primes of Ass $M$ not meeting $U$ is the kernel of the localization map $M\to M[U^{-1}]$, and is thus independent of the primary decomposition chosen.

I am just looking for a hint to get started. Also, if you have the book, what are the relevant theorems for solving this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $s\in U$ and $x\in M$ we have $sx=0\implies sx\in Q$, where $Q$ is a primary submodule of $M$ which appears in a primary decomposition of $(0)$ and $r_M(Q)\cap U=\emptyset$. Conclude that $x\in Q$.

For the converse, $x\in\cap Q_j$ with $r_M(Q_j)\cap U=\emptyset$. On the other side, for some $Q_i$ such that $r_M(Q_i)\cap U\ne\emptyset$ we get an $s_i\in r_M(Q_i)\cap U$, so $s_i^{k_i}M\subseteq Q_i$. In particular, $s_i^{k_i}x\in Q_i$. Now find an $s\in U$ such that $sx=0$.

Comment: In the converse part can it happen that there is no such $Q_i$ such that $r_M(Q_i) \cap U \neq \phi $user26857

Comment: @user371231 Of course, it can. In that case $\frac x1\in(0)[U^{-1}]$ and everything is clear.